# Proper Header Technique

Tags: php, html

What is the proper way to have headers? For example, PHP `include`, copy-and-pasting it between pages, iframes etc. I'm interested in having a header that I can easily edit from one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "proper" way. That said, copy-and-pasting and iframes are generally pretty bad ideas. Using includes is very common and usually a pretty good way of doing it. Even better would be to use the layout and templating facilities provided by an MVC framework, but this can be a steep learning curve and difficult to incorporate into an existing project.